# contributes.configuration property in vs code extension during development

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am developing a VS Code extension and I wanted to use `contributes.configuration` in package.json to set some configuration for the extension.

I have added this object:

```
"configuration": {
  "title": "Extension Name",
  "properties": {
    "git.sampleProp1": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false,
      "description": "Sample Prop 1"
    },
    "git.sampleProp2": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false,
      "description": "Sample Prop 2"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am having a hard time to figure out how to test this during development. When I press F5 in vs code my Extension Development Host opens up, the extension works just fine, but I am not able to find any UI in it from which I can modify and text my extension for various configurations.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Goto Settings -> Extensions to see the configurations for your extension. You will find your extension name in the list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you'll want to open up Visual Studio's Developer Tools.

You can access developer tools by opening the command palette:

Windows/Linux: `Control` + `Shift` + `P`

Mac: `Command` + `Shift` + `P`

Then type **Toggle Developer Tools**

Comment: I specifically wanted to see somewhere how my configuration properties are rendered to the UI and wanted to play with the checkboxes and see how my extension is responding. How can I do that there?